# Как с помощью JS вставить скопировать текст из одного поля в другое

Tags: javascript

У меня есть форма ввода:

```html
<form id="form01" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/add-car/new}" th:object="${carEntity}">
    <input type="text" id="input01" th:field="*{time}">
    <input type="time" id="input02" th:field="*{time}">
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что Thymeleaf ни как не хочет заносить значение из переменной time в поле ввода. Я понял, что без JS тут не обойтись, а я его ваще не знаю. Как мне с помощью JS скопировать значение value из поля input01 в input02 при нажатии на кнопку Save или при отрисовке формы, если это возможно?

Пробовал сделать вот так:

```html
<form name="form01" ...>
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setVal()">Сохранить</button>
</form>
<script>
    function setVal() {
        document.getElementById("input02").value = "21:45";
    }
</script>
```

Не работает

Comment: А зачем вы всё это обернули в форму?

Comment: как в туториале было, так и сделал. А как надо?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn_save').click(function(){ // отлавливаем нажатие
     var input01 = $("#input01").val(); // извлекаем текст из input01       
    $("#input02").val(input01); //записываем текст в input02 (меняем значение value)        
});

 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn_save">Save</button>
```

Comment: Не работает. Эта функция даже не вызывается.

Comment: вы подключили библиотеку js?

Comment: нет, я не настолько силен в JS. Что за библиотека?